# Solo se me pintan 2 de 3 alertas de SweetAlert

Tags: javascript, php, fetch, sweetalert2

Me encuentro practicando, creando mi propio CRUD. Estoy en la seccion de crear nuevos usuarios, donde tengo 3 alertas, la primera avisa que el nombre de usuario ya existe, la segunda que el correo ya esta registrado y la ultima es para decir que el nuevo usuario se creo correctamente. Las dos primeras funcionan bien, pero la tercera alerta no se muestra y tampoco me arroja errores. Al principio intente con if anidados creyendo que ese era el problema, asi que lo cambie por swicht case pero sigue sin aparecer la bendita alerta. Espero puedan ayudarme, ya llevo un dia (sin contar hoy) estancada. Gracias por leer

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" >
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/sweetalert2.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">
<title>Creacion de Usuario</title>
</head>
<body>
<header class="header">
    <img src="" alt="banner">
</header>

<main>
    <div class="contenedor">
        <h1>Creación de Usuario</h1>
        <div class="contenedor-login-nuevo-usuario">
            
            <!-- <div class="imagen-login">
                <img src="img/usuarios.png" alt="imagene-sesion">
            </div> -->
            <form id="formulario-nuevo-usuario">
                <div class="campos">
                    <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="nombre" title="Solo se aceptan letras" pattern="^[A-Za-zÑñÁÉÍÓÚáéíúóÜ\s]+$" required>
                </div>
                <div class="campos">
                    <label for="apellido">Apellido:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="apellido" title="Solo se aceptan letras" pattern="^[A-Za-zÑñÁÉÍÓÚáéíúóÜ\s]+$" required>
                </div>
                <div class="campos">
                    <label for="email">Correo:</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" pattern="^[a-z0-9]+(\.[_a-z0-9]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,15})$" title="Email incorrecto" required>
                </div>
                <div class="campos">
                    <label for="user">Usuario:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="user" title="El usuario es requerido" required>
                </div>
                <div class="campos">
                    <label for="password">Contraseña:</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password"  required>
                    <span id="requisitos-password" class="contact-form-error none">
                        <h4>La contraseña debe cumplir con los siguientes requisitos:</h4>
                        <ul>
                            <li id="mayuscula" class="invalido">Al menos una letra mayúscula</li>
                            <li id="number" class="invalido">Al menos un número</li>
                            <li id="blank" class="invalido">Sin espacios en blanco</li>
                            <li id="length" class="invalido">Tener 6 caracteres</li>

                        </ul>  
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="campos">
                    <label for="password">Confirmar Contraseña:</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password2" required>
                </div>
                <div class="contenedor-btn">
                    <button type="submit" id="boton-registrar" name="boton-registrar" value="registrar">Crear</button> 
                </div>
            </form>
            
        </div>
    </div>


</main>
</body>
<script src="js/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="./js/envio_datos_registro_usuarios.js" ></script>
</html>
```

JS donde estan las alertas

```
const d=document;
d.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e=>{
sendDatosForm ();
});
function sendDatosForm () {
let $form=d.getElementById('formulario-nuevo-usuario'),
$accion=d.getElementById('boton-registrar').value;
$form.addEventListener('submit', e=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    const datos=new FormData($form);
    datos.append('accion', $accion);
    fetch('./modelo/registrar_usuarios.php', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: datos,
        })
    .then(res=>{return res.ok ?(res.json()) :Promise.reject(res);})
    .then(data=>{ console.log(data)

        if (data.accion === 'registrar') {
            switch (data.respuesta) {
                case 'usuario existe':
                    Swal.fire({
                        title: 'El Usuario ya existe',
                        text: 'Por favor, coloca otro',
                        type: 'error'

                    });
                    break;
                case 'correo ya registrado':
                    Swal.fire({
                        title: 'Correo ya registrado',
                        text: 'Por favor, coloca otro',
                        type: 'error'

                    });
                    break;
                case 'correcto':
                    Swal.fire({
                        title: 'Registro Exitoso',
                        text: 'Presiona OK para ir al login',
                        type: 'success',
                        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
                        confirmButtonText: 'OK!' 

                    })
                .then (resultado => {
                        if (resultado.value){
                            window.location.href= 'index.html';
                            }
                        })      
                
                    break;
            }
    }
    })
    .catch(err=>{
    console.log(err); 
})
.finally(()=>{
    console.log('Esto se ejecutará independientemente del resultado de la Promesa Fetch')
})
```

PHP

```
<?php  

$name=$_POST['nombre'];
$lastname=$_POST['apellido'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$user=$_POST['user'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
$password2=$_POST['password2'];
$accion=$_POST['accion'];

if ($accion==='registrar') {
    
    include '../modelo/conexiondb.php';

    try{
        $sql=$conexion->prepare('SELECT usuario FROM usuarios WHERE usuario=?');
        $sql->bind_param('s', $user);
        $sql->execute();
        $sql->store_result();
        $stmt=$conexion->prepare('SELECT email FROM usuarios WHERE email=?');
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        
        if ($sql->affected_rows>0) {
            $respuesta = array('respuesta' =>'usuario existe',
                                'accion'=>$accion);
            $sql->free_result();
        
        }else if ($stmt->affected_rows>0) {
            $respuesta = array('respuesta' =>'correo ya registrado',
                                'accion'=>$accion);
            $stmt->free_result();
        }else {
            $opciones = array('cost' => 12);
        $hash_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $opciones);
        $query=$conexion->prepare('INSERT INTO usuarios (nombre, apellido, email, usuario, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
        $query->bind_param('sssss', $name, $lastname, $email, $user, $hash_password);
        $query->execute();
        $query->store_result();
            $respuesta = array('respuesta' =>'correcto',
                                'tipo'=>$accion
            );
            $query->free_result();
            $query->close();
        }
        $sql->close();
        $stmt->close();
        
        $conexion->close();
    }catch(Exception $e){
    //En caso de un error, tomar la excepcion
    $respuesta = array('respuesta' =>$e->getMessage() );
     }
  echo json_encode($respuesta); 
    
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tal como dice la documentación de [afected_rows()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.affected-rows.php):

> Devuelve el número de filas afectadas por una consulta INSERT, UPDATE,
> o DELETE.
>
> Esta función sólo funciona con las consultas que actualizan una tabla.
> Con el fin de obtener el número de filas de una consulta SELECT, usar
> mysqli_stmt_num_rows() en su lugar.

Y si te fijas, las consultas donde lo aplicas son del tipo **SELECT**. Por lo tanto prueba cambiando `afected_rows()` por `num_rows()` y nos cuentas si te ha funcionado.

Comment: @masteguru Hola! Lamento responder tan tarde. Me sigue sin funcionar, es decir, la alerta de "Registro Exitoso" no aparece... ¿Tendrás otra alternativa?

Comment: Además ninguna de las 3 alertas se pintan

Comment: y si haces la consulta a pelo te devuelve algun resultado?

Comment: ¿A pelo? Disculpa mi ignorancia pero ¿a que te refieres?

Comment: Si, perdona, quiero decir que si sabes seguro lo que devuelven estas consultas: `SELECT usuario FROM usuarios WHERE usuario=?` y `SELECT email FROM usuarios WHERE email=?` si las haces "a pelo" directamente en la base de datos, mediante phpmyadmin o lo que uses para gestionar la base de datos, sustituyendo los **?** por los valores que le intentas pasar.  ¿te devuelven alguna fila?

Comment: Hola si! Verifique en Phpmyadmin y todo marcha bien. Buscaré otras soluciones. Gracias por tu apoyo

Answer (score 0):

Actualización era un error de tipografía. Estaba enviando {'respuesta' : 'correcto', 'tipo':'registrar'}. El índice 'tipo' es en realidad 'accion'

Comment: ¿y con affected_rows te funciona o finalmente has usado num_rows?  Es que veo raro que con affected_rows te funcione, pues según el manual no debería para consultas SELECT... es curiosidad simplemente.

Comment: Hola! Ni idea ya que cambie affected_rows por num_rows es mejor así. Usar buenas prácticas